# Best way to supply 120 VAC to a breadboard?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I am working on a project that requires me to take an input voltage of 120 VAC and drop it to 12 VDC in order to power a micro-controller. I have the circuit's schematic mapped out and I want to test verify the circuit's operation on a breadboard.

The issue I have is I do not have access to a bench-top AC power supply (why are AC power supplies so expensive?) so I am wondering: What are the best alternatives that I can use, to supply the 120 VAC to the breadboard?

Comment: there is no good way to supply 120 Vac to a breadboard ... doing something like that is strongly discouraged because it is a safety hazard

Comment: are you building a linear power supply? ... if you are, then place the transformer into a protective enclosure, so that you cannot accidentally contact the 120 Vac power line ... run the low voltage wires from the transformer secondary windings to the breadboard

Comment: _"God, why are AC power supplies **so expensive**?!?!"_ - you're kidding, right? Compared to the really expensive things in life, a 12VDC 1A wall wart is dirt cheap.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I know wall warts are cheap. I was referring to bench top AC power supplies. Modern ones start at $2K.

Comment: @jalilel1913 I think $2k for one of those is dirt cheap considering a trustworthy DC bench supplies seem to start at $900.

Comment: @DKNguyen, you make a good point. You get what you pay for, in most cases.

[link] (https://youtu.be/AZebK05T5mY) - I saw this video and thought perhaps I could feed the AC voltage to the breadboard in a similar fashion.

Comment: Just stay away from transformerless supplies.

Comment: In 1978 I built a 'bench top' power supply using a 12V transformer, LM317 adjustable voltage regulator, 50uA panel meter and 3 digit LED voltmeter IC. I still use it today. Don't need no stinkin' laboratory power supply!

Comment: @BruceAbbott, that's awesome! Let's break out the bell bottoms and cocaine while we're at it!

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your needs, but why do you need to verify the circuit's operation _on a breadboard_? And why would you need a $2k AC power supply just to provide 120VAC?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I'm not saying that I **need** a $2k power supply. Breadboards are typically used to prototype and test circuit designs. At least that's the way I was taught in college and the military. In this case, my in input voltage is 120VAC. I typically work with DC circuits so that's why I asked about the best way to provide the requisite 120VAC input voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at other answers and comments, I see that you have a PC-mount 120VAC->12VDC supply.

I suggest that you mount that supply in a suitable plastic box, with a switch and fuse, and solder the AC wires throught the fuse and switch, to the AC input terminals of the supply.  Then solder wires from the DC output terminals to pins that you can insert into your breadboard.  For convenience, you may want to add binding posts to the box as DC output terminals.

You could mount the supply on a piece of perfboard/veroboard inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AC-DC wall wart. Safe and cheap. Easy-peasy

You can get DC barrel jack connectors that fit into breads boards, or get plugs that turn the DC barrel jacks on wall-warts into alligator clips or screw terminal blocks that you can then connect to a breadboard. My go to is Adafruit for these.

I am unsure what you are exactly referring to when you say "AC power supply" but if what you have in mind is a tunable AC power supply with variable frequency and voltage that would be insanely expensive because it's tricky to produce a variable frequency, amplitude AC waveform. That's what a variable speed drive or motor inverter is and those don't even have to make a very perfect or clean sinusoid which would probably be expected of an AC power supply. The reason is for efficiency, we have to use switches that are only on or off. How do you make something that just goes in or off into a sine wave that contains all voltages between zero and peak? Answer: Not easily.

Comment: _"but if what you have in mind is a tunable AC power supply with variable frequency and voltage"_ - OP just wants to 'power a micro-controller' with it, but probably thinks he needs a fancy laboratory power supply or something.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Hey, I would choose one of those over a wall wart too.

Answer (score 1):

Switch mode power supplies are ill-suited to solderless breadboards, even if it was safe (and it isn’t).

You would be better off to make a prototype PCB and use a variac and isolation transformer for testing. Idiot-proof the PCB with an enclosure etc., as might be necessary.

There are some products that combine isolation and variac in one box, but most variacs are autotransformers and thus not isolated.

Comment: Gratitude for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic must include a 120V~ to 12V~ step down transformer that would provide the necessary isolation.

It is apparent that you do not have a 120V~ mains supply to test your unit.

If you do have a 240V~ mains supply then you would need a 240V~ to 120V~ step down adapter (used by travellers) into which your unit may be safely plugged in. You should ensure that the power rating is adequate for testing your unit.

Comment: Correct. I am using an IRM-03-12 to step down the voltage from 120VAC to 12VDC. which then would be fed to the micro-controller. You are also correct that the 120VAC mains supply is what I am lacking at this stage. Gratitude for commenting!.

Comment: Anytime, jalilel1913! What is your mains voltage?

Comment: @jalilel1913, IRM-03-12 has an input voltage range of 85-305V~.

Comment: If by "mains voltage" you mean input voltage, it would be 120VAC. @vu2nan

Comment: @jalilel1913, The mains voltage I am referring to is the utility supply.  If your utility supply is 120VAC then you may use a 1:1 isolation transformer. The secondary of the isolation transformer may be connected to the IRM-03-12 and the primary plugged into the 120VAC utility supply.

Comment: Ah, I see. Gratitude for the clarification! @vu2nan